# File path Completion in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm using sublime text as a code editor, I wasted time with writing file paths for photos and assets. I searched and I found two packages for file path completion, which are [AutoFileName](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoFileName) and [FuzzyFilePath](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FuzzyFilePath), but these packages only work for sublime text 2.

Are there alternative solutions for sublime text 3?

Comment: Both packages support ST3. Do you use [PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io/)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Auto​File​Name](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoFileName) now supports Sublime Text 3 as does [FuzzyFilePath](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FuzzyFilePath).

A search on [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/search/File%20paths) yields results for other similar packages too.

Answer (score 2):

probably what you want is [**AutoFileName**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoFileName)

Answer (score 0):

First install Package Control then search autofilename and install it.. u will see files in dropdown 
I am also using Sublime Text 3 and it works
[after u select css/ then all css file will appear in DD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhrKr.png)

Answer (score 0):

For a while I thought AutoFileName wasn't working, but the answer is that you must have the cursor in between two quotes for autocomplete to fire:

```
import '../';
```

(cursor should be after the / above)

If you just start typing like this it won't fire:

```
import '../
```

Super simple, once you know, and implied in the package documentation, but it took me a little while to figure out - I hope this will help somebody else.